# Select least 6 values across 100 columns in a MySQL row

Tags: mysql, subquery, mariadb

I have a table with 103 columns. First column (rowID) is the row index, the next one contains a date, and the third one contains a string (a name), then there are 100 columns (named A1 to A100) that each contain an integer. I am trying to write a query to fetch the lowest 6 values among those 100 columns, for each row.

Here is what I tried. I had to write out all 100 columns (is there a better way?), and this only gets me the smallest 1, and NOT the smallest 6:

```
SELECT LEAST(A1,A2,A3,A4,...A100) FROM myTable WHERE rowID=1
```

I am thinking maybe I can use 5 queries to run the least command each time, returning the result to the backend which will then exclude the column that contained the least value in the previous query. However I am not sure this is the best way because I am trying to keep it all within MySQL. Is there a way to use sub-queries to do this? Or another effective method. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I also need to know the columns from which those minimum 6 values were obtained.

Comment: It's almost certainly going to be better the sort the result array in your application and slice off the bottom 6 entries.

Comment: I forgot to add that I need to know the specific columns that have those minimums. Updating the question now.

Comment: What application framework are you using?

Comment: It's Phoenix (Elixir). I am just learning it, though, and so maybe I simply don't know how to do that. However Bill's answer below helps out! I will simply restructure the table. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you've got the flexibility to restructure the table, doing what Bill suggested is absolutely the right thing to do. It will make your life a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: Reconsider the decision to have an array spread across 100 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be storing a multi-valued attribute in a denormalized way.

If you need to do set-oriented comparisons on these values, they should be stored in *rows*, not columns.

You can "unpivot" them, so each value is on its own row, like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS ValNo, A1 AS Val FROM MyTable WHERE rowID=1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, A2 FROM MyTable WHERE rowID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, A3 FROM MyTable WHERE rowID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, A4 FROM MyTable WHERE rowID=1
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 100, A100 FROM MyTable WHERE rowID=1
```

Then by putting that into a subquery, get the lowest 6 values.

```
SELECT ValNo, Val
FROM ( ... subquery above ... ) AS t
ORDER BY Val
LIMIT 6
```

---

You would be better off to store a table with one column for the value, and up to 100 *rows* for each `rowId`:

```
CREATE TABLE MyNewTable (
  RowId INT,
  OrdinalId TINYINT, -- 1 to 100
  Aval INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (RowId, OrdinalId)
);
```

Then you can query it more simply:

```
SELECT OrdinalId, Aval
FROM MyNewTable
WHERE RowId = 1
ORDER BY Aval
LIMIT 6;
```

Comment: Thanks! (1) I might have an opportunity to redesign the database. Would it be better for performance, to transform the columns into rows, or else use the columns and unpivot them as you advised? (2) Please note that I also need to know what column names each of the minimum 6 values came from.

Comment: @Cogicero the ValNo column in the query he provided can be used as the column identifier. And in SQL you are almost always better off with rows than columns.... that will become obvious when you realize that `...` in the first part of the answer represents about 190 lines of query. That first query is basically to turn your data into the shape it should be in to begin with.

Comment: I agree with Uueerdo. Store the data in a normalized fashion, to make your queries simpler.

Comment: So after changing the database structure, then instead of the subquery in your second code listing, I will be selecting FROM (A1, A2, A3,..., A100), correct?  In that case, I am not sure how to select the column name? Thanks so much, Bill Karwin and Uueerdo.

Comment: No, after changing the structure, the query would just be something like `SELECT ValNo, Val FROM myNewTable WHERE valueGroupingId = 1 ORDER BY VAL LIMIT 6` _(where "valueGroupingId" is the former "row" id)_.

Comment: I added a more complete example above.